# Newly available Standard objects with the latest Salesforce API version

Tags: standard-objects, spring17

Is there a way we can find out the newly available Standard objects with the latest Salesforce API version (currently 39.0)? This may be useful for any future version too.

Answer (score 3):

You can check new objects under the release notes [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_api_objects_new.htm)

> AssetTokenEvent
>
> CommunityWorkspacesNode
>
> ForecastingUserPreference
>
> QuoteFeed
>
> SecurityCustomBaseline
>
> Stamp
>
> StampAssignment
>
> UserCriteria
>
> VoiceCall
>
> VoiceCallList
>
> VoiceCallListItem
>
> VoiceCallListShare
>
> VoiceCallShare
>
> VoiceMailContent
>
> VoiceMailContentShare
>
> VoiceUserLine
>
> VoiceUserLineShare
>
> VoiceVendorInfo
>
> VoiceVendorLine
>
> VoiceVendorLineShare

Comment: There is also a similar section for [new/changed Apex classes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm). Basically, it comes down to "read the release notes".

Comment: indeed, it does